# How to retrieve image url in MVC view from model

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api, mvc

I am new to Sitecore. I am trying to create a small demo which will display all the products with its image and description. 
 
But i am getting error in my view also i am not able to display anything.

here is my code: 
**ProductController**

```
        using MicrosoftDemo.Models;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
        using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

        namespace MicrosoftDemo.Controllers
       {
       public class ProductController : Controller
       {
        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var context = Sitecore.Context.Item;

            var products = context
                .GetChildren()
                .Where(x => x.TemplateID
                                .ToString() == "{6BDC57DE-9C93-4922-9GA8- 
                                      049J387ACBE2}");

            var productModelList = new List<ProductModel>();

            if (products != null && products.Any())
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    if (product == null)
                        continue;

                    var imgField = (ImageField)product
                        .Fields["ProductImage"];

                    var items = new ProductModel
                    {
                        ProductImage = MediaManager
                            .GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem),
                        ProductName = product
                            .Fields["ProductName"]
                            .Value,
                        ProductDescription = product
                            .Fields["ProductDescription"]
                            .Value
                    };
                    productModelList.Add(items);
                }
            }
            return View(productModelList);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
 @model IEnumerable<MicrosoftDemo.Models.ProductModel>
@using Sitecore.Mvc;


@if (Model.Any())
{
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
//                    how do i print multiple items am i doing anything wrong here ?@Html.Sitecore().Field not displaying anything
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h3>
                            <span>
                                @*I am getting error below cannot convert from string to SiteCore.Data.Items.Item*@
                                @Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductImage", item.ProductImage, new {@class = "img-responsive"})
                            </span>
                            @Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductName", item.ProductName)
                        </h3>
                        <br/>
                        <p class="myfont">@Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductDescription", item.ProductDescription)</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this ?
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

To explain why you are getting that, `@Html.Sitecore().Field` requires a field name and the item to work with. Right now you are passing it a property on your model which is a string.

To solve that you have 2 options.

#### Option 1, write the markup yourself:

Change:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductImage", item.ProductImage, new {@class = "img-responsive"})
```

to

```
<img src="@item.ProductImage" class="img-responsive" />
```

That would work, but it will not allow the content editor to edit the image in the Experience Editor.

#### Option 2, pass the item into the model

Currently your model is a list of:

```
var items = new ProductModel
{
    ProductImage = MediaManager
        .GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem),
    ProductName = product
        .Fields["ProductName"]
        .Value,
    ProductDescription = product
        .Fields["ProductDescription"]
        .Value
};
```

Rather than keep that, make your main model class an enumerable of `Item`

```
var productModelList = new List<Item>();
```

You can then replace this entire block:

```
if (products != null && products.Any())
{
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        if (product == null)
            continue;

        var imgField = (ImageField)product
            .Fields["ProductImage"];

        var items = new ProductModel
        {
            ProductImage = MediaManager
                .GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem),
            ProductName = product
                .Fields["ProductName"]
                .Value,
            ProductDescription = product
                .Fields["ProductDescription"]
                .Value
        };
        productModelList.Add(items);
    }
}
```

with

```
productModelList.AddRange(products);
```

Finally your markup would change to use the item and not the property name:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>
            <span>
                @Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductImage", item, new {@class = "img-responsive"})
            </span>
            @Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductName", item)
        </h3>
        <br/>
        <p class="myfont">@Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductDescription", item)</p>
    </div>
}
```

Its a bit more work, but it will enable the Experience Editor for all your fields.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting `cannot convert from string to SiteCore.Data.Items.Item` error is the fact that `Field` helper expects parameters:

- Name of the field
- Item from which the field should be taken
- optional parameters

Your `ProductImage` field is coming from `product` items you're looping in the controller. You need to pass that item in the model to your view:

1. Add `ProductItem` of type `Item` to your model class.
2. Set `ProductItem` in your loop like:

```
var items = new ProductModel
{
    ProductImage = MediaManager
        .GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem),
    ProductName = product
        .Fields["ProductName"]
        .Value,
    ProductDescription = product
        .Fields["ProductDescription"]
        .Value,
    ProductItem = product
};
```

3. and in cshtml:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("ProductImage", item.ProductItem, new {@class = "img-responsive"})
```

Comment: Marek, I might suggest you expand on the "why" here... (i.e. because the Field helper expects a Sitecore item)

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr you're right. Answer updated.